# Translation in Vue 3 script i18n

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I have tried so many ways to get translations working in my component script, but nothing is working.

I tried:

```
<script>
import i18n from '@/i18n'

export default {
  tabIcon: 'images',
  translation: this.$t("basicnavigation.tabs.logos"),
}
</script>
```

And get an error:

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$t')*

Then I tried:

```
<script>
import i18n from '@/i18n'

export default {
  tabIcon: 'images',
  translation: i18n.t("basicnavigation.tabs.logos"),
}
</script>
```

Got an error:

*TypeError: i18n.t is not a function*

Also tried just $t, also another error.

This is my main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import i18n from './i18n'
import "bootstrap"
import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';
import Spinner from '@/components/Spinner'
import "@/assets/scss/styles.scss";

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

i18n.setup()
app.use(pinia)
app.use(i18n.vueI18n)
app.use(router)
app.use('bootstrap')

    
app.component('BootstrapIcon', BootstrapIcon);
app.component('Spinner', Spinner)
app.mount('#app')
```

The i18n file:

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue'
import { createI18n, useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import { numberFormats } from './numbers'
import { arabicPluralRules } from './plurals'
import { datetimeFormats } from './datetimes'
import defaultMessages from '../translations/nl-NL.json'

export const supportedLocales = {
  'en-GB': { name: 'English', dir: 'ltr' },
  'nl-NL': { name: 'Nederlands', dir: 'ltr' },
}

export const defaultLocale = 'nl-NL'

let _i18n

function setup(options = { locale: defaultLocale }) {
  _i18n = createI18n({
    locale: options.locale,
    fallbackLocale: defaultLocale,
    messages: { [defaultLocale]: defaultMessages },
    numberFormats,
    datetimeFormats
  })

  setLocale(options.locale)

  return _i18n
}

function setLocale(newLocale) {
  _i18n.global.locale = newLocale
  setDocumentAttributesFor(newLocale)
}

async function loadMessagesFor(locale) {
  const messages = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `../translations/${locale}.json`
  )

  _i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages.default)

  return nextTick()
}

function setDocumentAttributesFor(locale) {
  const htmlElement = document.querySelector('html')

  htmlElement.setAttribute('lang', locale)
  htmlElement.setAttribute('dir', supportedLocales[locale].dir)
}

const { t } = useI18n({
  messages: {
    supportedLocales
  }
})

export default {
  get vueI18n() {
    return _i18n
  },
  setup,
  setLocale,
  loadMessagesFor,
  t
}
```

With in my component:

```
<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import i18n from '@/i18n'

export default {
  tabIcon: 'images',

  setup() {

    const translation = computed(() => i18n.t('basicconfiguration.tabs.logos'))

    return { translation }
  }
}
</script>
```

Ive searched for 2 hours and tried almost everything, but nothing is working.. what am I doing wrong? Could it be the router file?

Comment: The issue is in registering your i18n plugin

Comment: Ok.. and how can I make it so I can use translations in <script> or <script setup>?

Comment: You're in control of what's exported from i18n module. There's no `t` in `export default {`. `export default {
  tabIcon: 'images',` - this is not a proper definition of a comp. `t` should be used inside a computed in order to be reactive. vue-i18n has useI18n composable for composition api, as any other properly designed third-party lib, it's in the docs

Comment: I updated my i18n.js file and now I get the following error:

SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a `setup` function

Comment: @R-b-n The error means what it says. useI18n is supposed to be used in component setup instead of your own i18n module. You rarely ever need this i18n.js, only when i18n is used outside components

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/ultimate-guide-to-vue-localization-with-vue-i18n/ and we use a language swither and use locales in the paths.

Comment: The same article explains how useI18n is used in this case

Comment: Ok great, I fail to see why my answer is insufficient as I followed the tutorial completely and everything is working. Why is using this.$t not ok?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (dont change/add anything to the i18n file):

```
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    translation() {
     return this.$t('basicnavigation.tabs.logos')
    },
  },

  tabIcon: 'images',
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just use useI18n.

Comment: Yeah was suggested already, but didnt work, this does